# Read csv with unspecified trailing spaces after NA values

Tags: r

I have a set of csv files where missing values (NA) are followed by a variable number of spaces throughout the file.

What is the best way to get these values interpreted correctly as NA, instead of characters?

Below is an example of the data I am dealing with & what I have tried. Using a regex in the na.strings arguments doesn't seem to work.

Note that spaces are always trailing - if that helps at all!

```
x = data.frame(id = 1:5, missing = c(NA, "NA ", "NA  ", "NA    ", "NA                "), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(x, 'NA_test.csv')

read.csv('NA_test.csv', na.strings = c("NA[[:space:]]+"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`read.csv` ignores some arguments, so you have to use read.table. Unfortunately, `na.string` does not evaluate regexp. Additionally, `strip.white = TRUE` only removes whitespace from **unquoted** strings. This is the best you could do using `read.table`.

```
read.table('~/NA_test.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", na.strings = c(NA, "NA ", "NA  ", "NA    ", "NA                "), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  id missing
1  1      NA
2  2      NA
3  3      NA
4  4      NA
5  5      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions, but here is my go. I just delete all the whitespace with regex command and find if it is NA. 
The as.data.frame with the sapply is to keep all of the variables classes.

```
y <- read.csv('NA_test.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y

findNA <- function(x) {
  if (class(x) == 'character') {
    temp <- gsub(' ', '', x) 
    return(replace(temp, temp == 'NA', NA))
  } else { 
    return(x)  
  }
}

as.data.frame(sapply(y, findNA, simplify = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Re: @Ian Campbells comments

It seems like the best solution is just to look through every cell for NAs after loading. This is what I will use.

```
x = data.frame(id = 1:5, missing = c(NA, "NA ", "NA  ", "NA    ", "NA                "), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(x, 'NA_test.csv', row.names = FALSE)

y = read.csv('NA_test.csv', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
apply(y, 2, function(x) gsub("NA[[:space:]]+", NA, x))
```